# IndexError:index 11186 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 4141

Tags: python

There is a bug here, and every time it is run, the index number changes, while 'axis 0 with size 4141' remains the same

**File "D:\paper_work\CropPainter-master-main\code\datasets.py", line 154, in **getitem**
return self.iterator(index)
File "D:\paper_work\CropPainter-master-main\code\datasets.py", line 116, in prepair_training_pairs
lables = self.lables[index, :]**
**IndexError: index 11186 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 4141**

```
`def generated_train_batch_label(cls, csvpath):
    if cls == "Panicle":
        pipe_path = r'../data/Panicle/train/labels.pkl'
    if cls == "Rice":
        pipe_path = r'../data/Rice/train/labels.pkl'
    if cls == "Maize":
        pipe_path = r'../data/Maize/train/labels.pkl'
    if cls == "Cotton":
        pipe_path = r'../data/Cotton/train/labels.pkl'

    # 1 filenames.txt generate: run ../data/<cls>/images/.bat, replace to ../data/Panicle/train/filenames.txt
    # 2 label.pkl
    f1 = open(csvpath, "r")
    case_train = np.loadtxt(f1, delimiter=',', skiprows=0)
    case_train1 = np.array(case_train)
    # print(case_train1)
    scaler = MinMaxScaler()
    scaler.fit(case_train1)
    c = scaler.transform(case_train1)
    c = torch.from_numpy(c).float()
    print(c.shape)    #tensor.Size([4141, 18])
    with open(pipe_path, 'wb') as fw:
        pickle.dump(c, fw, protocol=2)`
```

```
def prepair_training_pairs(self, index):
      key = self.filenames[index]
      bbox = None
      data_dir = self.data_dir
      lables = self.lables[index, :]
      img_name = '%s/images/%s' % (data_dir, key)
      imgs = get_imgs(img_name, self.imsize,
                      bbox, self.transform, normalize=self.norm)

      wrong_ix = random.randint(0, len(self.filenames) - 1)
      wrong_key = self.filenames[wrong_ix]
      wrong_bbox = None
      wrong_img_name = '%s/images/%s' % \
                       (data_dir, wrong_key)
      wrong_imgs = get_imgs(wrong_img_name, self.imsize,
                            wrong_bbox, self.transform, normalize=self.norm)


      if self.target_transform is not None:
          lables = self.target_transform(lables)

      return imgs, wrong_imgs, lables, key  # captions

def prepair_test_pairs(self, index):
      key = self.filenames[index]
      bbox = None
      data_dir = self.data_dir
      lables = self.lables[index,:]
      img_name = '%s/images/%s' % (data_dir, key)
      imgs = get_imgs(img_name, self.imsize,
                      bbox, self.transform, normalize=self.norm)

      if self.target_transform is not None:
          lables = self.target_transform(lables)

      return imgs, lables, key  # captions

def __getitem__(self, index):
      return self.iterator(index)

def __len__(self):
      return len(self.filenames)`
```

Comment: What are the shapes of `self.filenames` and `self.labels` in `prepair_training_pairs`?

Comment: Load filenames from: ../data/Panicle\train\filenames.txt (20066)
labels:  (4141, 18)

Answer (score 0):

As you stated in the comments filenames are 20066 elements long, labels are 4141 elements long.
In `prepair_training_pairs` you use the same `index` to access both `self.filenames` and `self.labels`, since you define the `__len__` as the length of `filenames` the `index` can be up to 20065, using it to access `labels` will throw `IndexError` since `lables` is much shorter than that.

Consider why your `labels` are shorter than `filenames` and how to get the labels for each filename.